# Change opacity css with jquery selector

Tags: jquery, css, opacity

I am building a thumbnail of brands that have icon view and edit each other.. I want to hover all icon when one of them hovered.

Here the structure that I have ..

```
<div id="brands-wrapper">
                    <img class="brands" src="http://localhost/infodiskon/images/'.$data->image_brand.'">
                    <div id="icon-wrapper">
                        <a href="#" id="view">
                            <img src="http://localhost/infodiskon/assets/images/view_icon.png">
                        </a>
                        <a href="#" id="edit">
                            <img src="http://localhost/infodiskon/assets/images/edit_icon.png">
                        </a>
                    </div>
                    <h3>'.$data->brand_name.'</h3>
                    <h4>'.$data->location.'</h4>
                </div>
```

I have used a version 2.1.3 of jquery with google CDN.

And also I just trying to alert when icon view hovered . a script :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#view").hover(
            function() {
                alert("Yo");
            }
        );
    });
```

alert just showed up when the first item only hovered not with the other one..

What I want is to show all icon when one of them hovered??? I just want to change the opacity to 1. I can use :hover in css but it just working with only tag of it.

css

```
#icon-wrapper{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;left: 0;
}
#icon-wrapper .view, #icon-wrapper .edit{ 
    display: block;
    width: 194px;
    height: 94px;
    line-height: 94px;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: #363636;
    opacity: 0;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.view>img{margin-bottom: -16px;} 
.edit>img{margin-bottom: -10px;}
#icon-wrapper .view{margin-bottom: 6px;}
#icon-wrapper .view:hover, #icon-wrapper .edit:hover{
    opacity: .8;
}
```

Comment: you need to apply the `.hover` to a class which all elements share. At the moment, youre just binding it to one id called `#view`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to attach the class to all the elements you need hovered. You can still keep your id as you may need it for other functions.

HTML:

```
<div id="icon-wrapper">
    <a href="#" class="thumb" id="view">
        <img src="http://localhost/infodiskon/assets/images/view_icon.png">
    </a>
    <a href="#" class="thumb" id="edit">
        <img src="http://localhost/infodiskon/assets/images/edit_icon.png">
    </a>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(".thumb").hover(function() {
    $(this).parent().children().css("opacity", "0");//when mouseenter
}, function() {
    $(this).parent().children().css("opacity", "1");//when mouseleave
});
```

Comment: okey got it .. how do i select class edit when class view hovered . i just want to change opacity of it with jquery

Comment: @CodeGodie Could you explain the downvote on my answer?

Comment: how if class is different ?? like my structure above .. class view and edit. they have a different style in css

Comment: Please provide your CSS in your question, so that we can see what you currently have. The class on your elements should not be different, your IDs should be different, and your CSS should be pointing to those IDs

Comment: css updated.. http://postimg.org/image/609qaft6f/643d2ea9/ . this what i want to achieve . i have brand logo that have 2 icon . view and edit . i've used hover in css , but it just affect to that element it self. so i want to hover all icon when one of icon is hovered .. how do i do that ??

Comment: i see. In that case you need to do this in jquery `$(this).parent().children().css("opacity", "0"); ` see my updated jquer code

Comment: it's working .. @CodeGodie . and how to set when mouse out ??

Answer (score 1):

looks like you have multiple element with same IDs. IDs needs to be unique. you can use same class instead.

markup:

```
               <div class="icon-wrapper">
                    <a href="#" class="view">
                        <img src="http://localhost/infodiskon/assets/images/view_icon.png">
                    </a>
                    <a href="#" class="edit">
                        <img src="http://localhost/infodiskon/assets/images/edit_icon.png">
                    </a>
                </div>
```

script:

```
 $(".view").hover(
    function() {
       $(this).next().addClass('smclass');
    },function(){
       $(this).next().removeClass('smclass');
    }
);
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9w61mu1e/)**

Comment: you need to add the class to all your `a` elements

Comment: No, its working , [Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mihiruj/2c6x3f1d/1/), a little css and changed the class of 2nd anchor

Comment: okey, i dont know why its not working .. but i just want to know how do i select class edit when class view hovered and change css of it

Comment: use `$(this).next().addClass('smclass')`.see the updated demo.

Comment: @MilindAnantwar Could you point where there are **"multiple element with same IDs"** in the OP's code?

Comment: @SatwikNadkarny: 1) works only for first element. 2) ID selector have been used 3) i said looks like..

Comment: @MilindAnantwar *"3) I said looks like"* **So basically what you're saying is that your answer is based on your assumption!!!** The HTML structure provided by the OP in the question clearly indicates that your assumption is not the case *(which is why I posted my question for clarification)*. ***Hence, it would make more sense if you could answer the question based on the information the OP has provided rather than making assumptions which clearly are not the case.***

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to attach a class to the `anchor` tags or the `img` tags. You can instead use the `direct children` selector in `CSS`. This will save you the burden of attaching a class every time a new anchor element is added.

**NOTE** : I have just edited the source of the `img` tags (and added some `CSS`) to display an image.

Given that your HTML is of the format :

```
<div id="brands-wrapper">
    <img class="brands" src="http://localhost/infodiskon/images/'.$data->image_brand.'" />
        <div id="icon-wrapper">
            <a href="#" id="view">
                <img src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" id="edit">
                <img src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg" />
                </a>
        </div>
     <h3>'.$data->brand_name.'</h3>

     <h4>'.$data->location.'</h4>

</div>
```

What you can do is use the `jQuery` to target all the direct children of the `div` having the `id` "icon-wrapper".

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#icon-wrapper > a").hover(function () {
        alert("Yo");
    });
});
```

This will help you to target all anchor tags which are direct children within your div.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#icon-wrapper > a").hover(function () {
        alert("Yo");
    });
});
```

```css
#icon-wrapper > a > img {
    border: 2px solid Black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="brands-wrapper">
    <img class="brands" src="http://localhost/infodiskon/images/'.$data->image_brand.'" />
        <div id="icon-wrapper">
            <a href="#" id="view">
                <img src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg" />
            </a>
            <a href="#" id="edit">
                <img src="http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg" />
                </a>
        </div>
     <h3>'.$data->brand_name.'</h3>

     <h4>'.$data->location.'</h4>

</div>
```

Comment: ah i apologize for the downvote.. I thought you were saying something completely different. You answer will work, it is just another way of calling the selectors.

Comment: css updated.. postimg.org/image/609qaft6f/643d2ea9 . this what i want to achieve . i have brand logo that have 2 icon . view and edit . i've used hover in css , but it just affect to that element it self. so i want to hover all icon when one of icon is hovered .. how do i do that ??